# Cannot resolve symbol error for JSONArray in IntelliJ with Java

Tags: arrays, json, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I have added the following in my POM file within IntelliJ (I'm using Maven)

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
     </dependency>
```

But for my code I am getting Cannot Resolve Symbol error when creating a "JSONArray" object.

I have tried using 
    import org.json.jsonarray
    and
    import org.json.simple.jsonarray

I have exited IntelliJ and rebuilt the project. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

```
 public class Countries {

   private static String url;
   private static int count;
   private static int sCode;
   private static List<CountriesData> cList;

  public void GetCountries() throws Exception
   {
      try        {
         url = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all";

         // make get request to fetch json response from restcountries
         Response resp = get(url);

         //Fetching response in JSON as a string then convert to JSON Array
         JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(resp.asString());
```

[image: Module Dependencies]

Comment: Does it show completion if you type "import org.json.simple."? Please check that library was added as a dependency to your module in "Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies"

Comment: It doesn't complete but have added all the libraries as dependencies. Not sure what I am missing..

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot from "Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies" ?

Comment: Thanks just added

Comment: Please try to run "Invalidate Caches". If it doesn't help please attach sample project for investigation.

Comment: oh. That fixed it! Thanks very much

Comment: not sure how to mark your answer as the correct one..

Comment: You are welcome! Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running "File | Invalidate Caches" helped in this case.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.